# How can I send auto mail with thunderbird with bash scripting and xdotool?

Tags: bash, automation, thunderbird

What I want to do is, if a condition is met, such as like if x=5, I want it to send a mail to me, automatically. With thunderbird, you can partially do this, but can't click send obviously...

This thunderbird command alone, works in that regard:

```
thunderbird -compose "subject='test',to='someaddress@mail.com',body='this and that'"
```

Also this xdotool command work:

```
xdotool mousemove 570 179 click 1
```

this 570 179 is where the SEND button is. But, if I combine these like this. This wont work(changing && s to ; don't work either):

```
thunderbird -compose "subject='test',to='someaddress@mail.com',body='this and that'" && sleep 2 && xdotool mousemove 576 218 click 1
```

However, when I only do thunderbird command, then in another terminal if I apply this xdotool mouse click, it works only then.

I was researching on this subject, they said this might be about x server, so they advised something like this:

```
thunderbird -compose "subject='something',to='someaddress@mail.com',body='
something'" && sleep 5; xdotool windowactivate $(xdotool getactivewindow) sleep 5 && xdotool mousemove 576 218 click 1
```

Comment: That feels wrong - thunderbird is a graphical interface. Why not \uUse a sendmail compatible client - like msmtp, and send the mail via sendmail from the terminal?

Comment: You mean like mutt? I tried it, it would probably work though. But why this doesn't work? I am obsessed with this..